# UnitTest Slim's Error Handler Responses

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, slim

I'm developing an API service using Slim PHP v3 and I'm trying to Unit Test my development using PHPUNIT.

I have the following in a controller( UserController) mapped to a route in Slim

```
try {
          $model = $this->model->findOrFail($args['id']);
          $response->write($model);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
          throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }


        return $response;
```

to which Slim would "handle the error" and return a 500 status code( which works when I execute in browser)

Now I have the following test( UsersTest)...

```
protected function request($method, $url, array $requestParameters = [])
    {
        ob_start();
        $request = $this->prepareRequest($method, $url, $requestParameters);
        $response = new Response();
        $app = $this->app;
        $this->response = $app($request, $response);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    function testGetUserFail()
        {

            $response = $this->request('GET','/users/1',[]);
            $this->assertThatResponseHasStatus(500, print_r($this->responseData(), true)); // does and assertEquals test
        }
protected function setUp()
    {
         putenv('ENV=testing');
         require __DIR__ . '/../../src/bootstrap.php';
         $this->app = $app;
         $c = $app->getContainer();
         $c['settings']['displayErrorDetails'] = ('development' === (getenv('ENV') ?: 'development'));
         $c['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
              return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {
                  return $c['response']->withStatus(500)
                                       ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                                       ->write(json_encode(['error'=>true, 'error_msg'=>$exception->getMessage()]));
              };
          };
         //$app->run();
    }
```

The test is detects whether or not the mock request sends back the correct status code but for some reason it errors out on thrown exception rather than continuing on with returning a propoer status code

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) UsersTest::testGetUserFail Exception: No query results for model
>   [App\Model\Users].
>
> ~/app/src/Controller/UsersController.php:32
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 2, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1. Complete.

Like I said if i run the code in a browser it works as expected but not in phpunit test...

Is my testing logic wrong? should I be testing for the exception and not an expected status code?